# Is this proper data design

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

I became responsible for a legacy system with a legacy database inside.
It has modeled the data in a for me strange way for instance take a look at this generic table :

```
nr          jdptype    jdpid       jdpdescr
----------- ---------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           jrelation  1           Leverancier
2           jrelation  2           Klant
3           jrelation  3           Dealer
4           jcontact   1           Contact
5           jaddress   1           Hoofdadres
6           jcomm      1           Phone
7           jcomm      2           Fax
8           jcomm      3           Email
9           jcomm      4           Internet
10          jcomm      5           Mobile
11          jfunction  2           Eigenaar
13          jfunction  4           Medewerker
14          jfunction  5           Ontwerper
15          jcountry   2           België
16          jcountry   3           Duitsland
17          jcountry   4           Nederland
18          jcountry   5           Engeland
19          jcountry   6           Frankrijk
20          jfunction  1           Ontw. Verk.
21          jlanguage  2           Nederlands
35          jtitle     2           Juff.
36          jaddress   4           Leveradres
38          jtitle     3           Dhr
39          jcountry   7           China
41          jaddress   5           Filiaal
42          jrelation  4           Architect
43          jrelation  5           Aannemer
44          jlanguage  3           Frans
45          jlanguage  4           Duits
46          jfiliaal   2           FrWe
47          jfiliaal   3           FrZo
48          jfiliaal   4           BoTu
49          jtitle     4           Prof
50          jtitle     5           Prof.
52          jtitle     7           Ing.
53          jtitle     8           Mr.
54          jtitle     9           Mevr.
55          jtitle     10          Dhr. Ing.
56          jtitle     11          Dhr. Ir.
57          jtitle     12          Mevr. Ing.
58          jtitle     13          Mevr. Ir
59          jtitle     14          Dhr. & Mevr.
60          jtitle     15          M. et Mme.
61          jtitle     16          Mlle
62          jtitle     17          Mme.
64          jrepres    3           J. Van Genechten
70          jrepres    9           R. Verschueren
75          jrepres    14          D. Verschueren
77          jrepres    15          Geen
78          jfunction  6           Verkoper
79          jfunction  7           Medew. Verk.
80          jfunction  8           Vertegenwoordiger
82          jrepres    17          S. Van Onckelen
83          jrepres    18          L. Jacobs
84          jrepres    19          R. Schoeters
85          jrepres    20          L. Delen
86          jrepres    21          B. Bouvé
87          jrepres    22          P. Van Haute
88          jfiliaal   1           MeMe
89          jrepres    16          E. Heykants
90          jfiliaal   5           Arro
91          jfiliaal   6           OfZo
```

The nr is the primary key, but actually for me this looks like several tables that are thrown together.
My gut feeling would be to create a relationtype table, a communicationtype table, a country table and so on.

It violates normalisation rules in the current state, because jpddescr does not relate really to nr, but to the combination of jdptype and jdpid.

Are my assumptions correct and should I consider refactoring this to a proper design, or is there anything I am missing which is in favor of this type of 'generic' design ?

I stumbled upon this when trying to create an entity diagram. Really annoying to keep having to create navigation properties to this table, for say a relation where there is nothing to stop you from filling in an id for a function.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem quite odd, but a proper fix requires deeper knowledge of the use case.

I would assert that creating many tables has its own drawbacks, and specifically in this case won't be a 1-to-1 replacement as the current implementation is flexible with regards to the possible types (its unlimited vs. a constant set of tables).

I would replace the `jdptype` with a foreign key linking to a `jdptypes` table to improve the design and performance.

Answer (score 1):

As a domain it's effectively a sum type / tagged union, aka One True Lookup Table.  Hopefully, there's at least a unique constraint declared on (jdptype, jdpid).  You correctly point out that it includes a transitive dependency, and hence there's a risk of update anomalies.  However, I'm less concerned about that and more concerned about the fact that any code that reads data that relates to this table won't know what domain to expect.  If I query, will I be getting an address, title, country, language, phone number, or something else?  It could be a mix, so I'll have to handle each row on a case-by-case basis, instead of processing whole sets at a time.  It's also likely to be pervasive through the code since every module's lookup table is likely rolled into this one, so the case logic will be repeated in numerous places.  What's more, it's a bit more difficult to add new attributes to the database for specific types of values, like international dialing codes for phone numbers or ISO 2-digit codes or neighbors for countries.  Want to build a localization table keyed by keyword and language?  Watch out, your translation might depend on a phone number instead of a language.  The easiest way to overcome many of these issues is to start adding new tables per type, which defeats the original purpose of having it all in one table.  Others could be overcome via check constraints, which will be more complicated and less efficient than the equivalent foreign key constraints would've been, if they're supported by the DBMS.

To refactor it, I would create a view for each type's subset of rows, possibly joining with any additional table which maps one-to-one onto these rows.  Then work my way through the system to rewrite any references to the base table.  Then, I could decompose the base table and replace the views with separate tables, and finally create the necessary foreign key constraints to enforce referential integrity.  However, before you start any refactoring, I suggest you check the existing data to verify that your assumptions about the correctness of the data hold in fact.  Usually, anything that can be recorded, will be recorded.